# How to diagnose a Cruise Control system (Subaru Forester 2002)

Tags: troubleshooting, subaru, cruise-control, forester

The Cruise Control on my 2002 Forester S stopped working recently. For some time I had problems engaging the CC altogether, requiring multiple clicks on the activation push-button. Then it stopped working completely.

On a retrospect, I may have confused a possibly-bad CC (on-wheel) lever with the button.

Anyway, the green and amber bulbs of the button died some time ago, and I thought maybe the burnt bulb opens the circuit, so it cannot be engaged. Searching for replacement reference, I found replacement bulbs at RadioShack, and this week I finally had the time to replace the bulbs on the CC switch, and on the way, the wipers de-icer.

Unfortunately, replacing the bulbs did not solve the problem, and the CC does not engage. How can I troubleshoot the problem source? How do I know if this is the lever, wiring or the module itself (whatever this one may be)?

Comment: It's going to be in one of two places: Either the cruise control motor is bad, or the switch you use to set your speed is bad (Not the one on the dash which turns it on, but the one which you actually use to set it). My vote would be on the switch, not the control motor, but I'll wait on @BobCross to respond as he's the Subie guru.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my bet is the switch (which I called the lever) too. But, before initiating a follow-up question on how to get to that switch, I started with the basic how-to.

Comment: Could also be brake switch that turns off cruise control when brakes are applied. On my Ford, it was a switch on brake master cylinder. Brake fluid had invaded switch and caused it to initially work intermittently and later fail.

Comment: @philcolbourn - thanks, good idea. Any idea how to diagnose that? How do I access that switch?

Comment: I found this diagram - perhaps you could find another that is exactly how your car is set up. http://www.subaruoutback.org/forums/80-electrical-electronics/41640-brake-controller-wiring-brake-signal-tap-point.html

Comment: This diagram suggests you may have a brake, clutch and neutral switch that must work for your cruise control to work.

Comment: @philcolbourn - thanks for the diagrams. At this point, I don't really have a clue how to access these switches.

Comment: My guess is that they will be physically attached to brake and clutch pedals near their pivot points. Try looking for them by lying up-side-down with your head in your foot well and your back on your seat.

Comment: BTW, did you find diagrams for your model of car?

Comment: @philcolbourn - no, I did not look for them, as the diagrams you provided show a straight forward circuit, that I believe is identical to the Forester one. Anyway, I did not get to actually look for the switch yet. I still suspect it is the on-wheel-switch.

Comment: Any updates on this issue? If so, we'd love to hear about it!

Comment: @Zaid - I could not diagnose and find the source of the problem. One thing I did was to take the CC acceleration cable that goes from the vacuum module to the engine throttle apart on the engine side (I could not unmount the vacuum module) and drain a generous amount of WD40 into the cable, thinking that if there is a friction build-up in the cable, it will be released by the lube. Unfortunately this did not help as well. A couple of months ago I replaced the car for a new Forester.